# Using a cdn to serve custom polymer elements in production

Tags: polymer, cdn

We are planning on serving our custom polymer elements from our production Akamai CDN which supports http/2.

We won't have more than 40 components overall and we aren't writing apps. These elements get served from static HTML pages produced by a cms.

We don't want to use bower/vulcanize.

Can we do this without getting burned?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes we will have polymer and webcomponents-lite.js out there as well of course. I'm a little worried about versioning with the CDN.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in it. All you have to do is give `CDN's` address in the `link` tag. Indeed you can use `base` tag to define the common path and then define relative path in your `link` tag. The only thing you have to keep in mind is that either you'll have to move `Polymer` or any third party component also to your CDN(including polymer.html and webcomponents-lite) or you'll have to use something like `polygit` for Polymer components.

Comment: Polygit is not intended for production. See constraints at polygit.org: `"This server concept is primarily for hit-and-run testing, jsbins, etc. The performance is less than ideal and there is very little error reporting or other niceties."`